# Mysterious folder icons briefly appear in Chrome bookmarks bar

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

When switching profiles in Google Chrome, there are two folder icons that sometimes briefly appear in the bookmarks bar. They are never there for very long. I managed to screencapture them, but it's not a very good picture because the "crash" recovery bar is in the way.

[image: mysterious folder icons]

Any idea what these icons are, and why the appear sometimes? It's not causing any problems, I'm just super curious what they are and why they have started appearing in recent releases of Chrome. I did a Google image search for the icons, and just a regular Google search, but these didn't turn up anything.

Comment: The link for your screenshot is not working

Comment: Worked for me, but I've never seen this before. What happens if you click on it or right click on it? Can you see any names, links, settings?

Comment: @MC10 I don't have time to click on them because they disappear too fast. I barely had enough time to hit "Print Screen" to get a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the [Managed Bookmarks](https://wpsit.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-push-bookmarks-to-users-in.html) folder. The little grid of squares is supposed to be a business building. A G Suite administrator can create this folder for their users via the G Suite admin console > Device management > Chrome > User Settings > User Experience > Managed Bookmarks.

[image: Example of managed bookmarks folder]

It looks a bit different after the Sept 4, 2018 "10th Anniversary" update. The "building" is harder to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are bookmarks folders. Bookmarks folders are created automatically when you use chrome on more than one device, or use your Gmail account with several browsers.

[More on Bookmarks folders here:](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/188842?hl=en)
[image]

The reason they only appear for a second, is because after chrome has finished loading the settings for a certain user, it hides them from view to look cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your link doesn't offer any support of what you are saying, as far as I can tell. Do you have a better citation or source?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no source for my answer, I gathered this from personal experience. The link was simply to prove the existence of bookmarks folders. If you wish to confirm/deny my explanation, you will need to contact Google support at https://support.google.com/ and ask this question to them. I would suggest the Chrome Help Forum at http://tinyurl.com/nssn8xj